# Styled-components vs Emotion - How to reapplicate css`style` function on Styled-components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components, emotion

I have a code using `Emotion` library. So far, everything works perfectly...

But checking the documentation, I saw that `Styled-components` already absorb some of the features of `Emotion` library; as the use of `css` in javascript.

But I'm not able to replicate the usage as least similar than `Emotion`.

Here is a full example (Using `Emotion`):

https://codesandbox.io/s/grouping-table-head-ant-design-demo-s7hb6?file=/index.js

Basically I want to create a CSS with some dynamic styles (Depending on an array of objects).
Works fine and it's clean... but I'm issue is knowing if this code can reapply using `Styled-components` (using the `css` notation).

Something similar to this article (I cannot make it work):

https://medium.com/styled-components/announcing-native-support-for-the-css-prop-in-styled-components-245ca5252feb

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for this functionality on `styled-components`; in the bottom line, is not possible.

Other alternatives are to use `CSS Modules`, `Emotion`, `styled jsx` or similar... but with `styled-components` is not possible so far.